# Is $R= \{(1,1), (2,2), (3,3), (1,2),(2,1),(1,3),(3,1)\}$ an equivalence relation$?$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I am not able to understand why $R= \{(1,1), (2,2), (3,3), (1,2),(2,1),(1,3),(3,1)\}$ is not an equivalence relation.Or is it$??$

Comment: If it was then the equivalence class of $ 1$ would be $\{1,2,3\}$, the equivalence class of $2$ would be $\{2,1\}$.  These two sets are not disjunct.

Answer (score 2):

It is not because $(3,1)$ and $(1,2)$ should imply $(3,2)$ but $(3,2)$ in not in your relation.